# Overload resolution of user-defined type conversion

Tags: c++, type-conversion, overloading, overload-resolution

I considered a type conversion from one type to the other, which are defined by two way, i.e., type conversion constructor and type conversion function.

```
struct to_type;
struct from_type{
   operator to_type()const;
};
struct to_type{
   to_type() = default;
   to_type(const from_type&){}
};
from_type::operator to_type()const{return to_type();}

int main(){
    from_type From;
    to_type To;
    To = From;

    return 0;
}
```

gcc (v13.0.0, but seems to be same even in v4.9.4) don't throw any error and just call **type conversion constructor** in the above code.

On the other hand, clang (v16.0.0, but seems to be same even in v7.6.0) throw a "ambiguous" compile error like the following.

```
prog.cc:14:10: error: reference initialization of type 'to_type &&' with initializer of type 'from_type' is ambiguous
    To = From;
         ^~~~
prog.cc:3:4: note: candidate function
   operator to_type()const;
   ^
prog.cc:7:4: note: candidate constructor
   to_type(const from_type&){}
   ^
prog.cc:5:8: note: passing argument to parameter here
struct to_type{
       ^
1 error generated.
```

It seems to be so curious that two major compiler show different result for this simple code. Is either compiler don't match with the standard for C++? I guess this overload resolution related to [[over.ics.rank]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.match.best#over.ics.rank), but I could not concluded which compiler's behavior match to the standard.

Or do my source code contains undefined behavior?

---

[ADD 2022-12-21T00:20Z]

Following the comment by Artyer, I tried `-pedantic` compile option for gcc, and now **gcc also output error** message.

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:14:10: error: conversion from 'from_type' to 'to_type' is ambiguous
   14 |     To = From;
      |          ^~~~
prog.cc:9:1: note: candidate: 'from_type::operator to_type() const'
    9 | from_type::operator to_type()const{return to_type();}
      | ^~~~~~~~~
prog.cc:7:4: note: candidate: 'to_type::to_type(const from_type&)'
    7 |    to_type(const from_type&){}
      |    ^~~~~~~
prog.cc:5:8: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'constexpr to_type& to_type::operator=(to_type&&)'
    5 | struct to_type{
      |        ^~~~~~~
```

This suggests that at least the default behavior of gcc without `-pedantic` don't match with the requirements of C++ standard for this source code.

Comment: Does not compile on gcc with `-pedantic`, and I think this is an ambiguous conversion based on [[over.ics.rank]p(3.3)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.match.best#over.ics.rank-3.3) being the only way to pick one user-defined conversion sequence over another (I think)

Comment: The program is well-formed and clang is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case clang is right, this behaviour is defined in [[over.best.ics.general]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.best.ics.general), and standard even mentions that such a conversion is ambiguous explicitly under the sample code to [[over.best.ics.general]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.match.best#over.best.ics.general-10) (the scenario under the link is in fact considers another kind of ambiguity, but resolution to user-defined pair of conversion constructor and conversion operator is one of the candidates, so I removed the part of the code with another candidate):

```cpp
class B;
class A { A (B&);};
class B { operator A (); };
...
void f(A) { }
...
B b;
f(b); // ... an (ambiguous) conversion b → A (via constructor or conversion function)
```

---

In order to break the name resolution down, I'd like to represent the conversion sequence (`To = From;`) as an assignment operator function:

```cpp
to_type& operator=(to_type&& param) { } // defined implicitly by the compiler
```

The actual conversion happens when `param` needs to get into existence out of `From` argument of type `from_type`. The compiler then needs to decide step by step:

1. Which type the conversion sequence from `from_type` to `to_type&&` is of? (**standard**/**user defined**/**ellipsis**):

   - The types `from_type` is user defined, but `to_type&&` is of reference type, and reference binding could be considered identity (i.e. standard) conversion. However it's not the case, since `from_type` and `to_type` are not the same and cannot be bound directly ([[over.ics.ref]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.ics.ref#2)):

   > When a parameter of reference type is not bound directly to an argument expression, the conversion sequence is the one required to convert the argument expression to the referenced type according to [[over.best.ics]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.best.ics).

   - Without reference binding there is no any other standard conversion sequence that may suit here. Let's consider **user-defined conversion**. [[over.ics.user]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.match.best#over.ics.user) gives us the following definition:

   > A user-defined conversion sequence consists of an initial standard conversion sequence followed by a user-defined conversion ([[class.conv]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.conv)) followed by a second standard conversion sequence. If the user-defined conversion is specified by a constructor ([[class.conv.ctor]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.conv.ctor)), the initial standard conversion sequence converts the source type to the type of the first parameter of that constructor. If the user-defined conversion is specified by a [conversion function](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.conv.fct), the initial standard conversion sequence converts the source type to the type of the implicit object parameter of that conversion function.

   This sounds about right to me: we need to convert `from_type` argument to `to_type` temporary in order for `to_type&&` to bind to the argument, thus the sequence is either

   - *`from_type` -> `const from_type&` for the converting constructor argument `to_type(const from_type&)` -> `to_type&&` for the move-assignment operator of `to_type& operator=(to_type&&)`*

   **OR**

   - *`from_type` -> implicit-object-parameter of type `const from_type&` for conversion function `operator to_type() const` -> `to_type&&` for the move-assignment operator of `to_type& operator=(to_type&&)`*.
2. Now we have two possible conversion sequences of the same kind (*user-defined*). For this scenario [[over.best.ics.general]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.best.ics#general-10) says the following:

> If there are multiple well-formed implicit conversion sequences converting the argument to the parameter type, the implicit conversion sequence associated with the parameter is defined to be the unique conversion sequence designated the ambiguous conversion sequence. For the purpose of ranking implicit conversion sequences as described in [[over.ics.rank]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.ics.rank).

The **Ranking implicit conversion sequences** documentation then gives the following clues about deciding on which conversion (of the same sequence type) should take precedence for user-defined sequences ([[over.ics.rank]/3.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.ics.rank#3.3), emphasis mine):

> User-defined conversion sequence `U1` is a better conversion sequence than another user-defined conversion sequence `U2` if they contain the same user-defined conversion function or constructor or they initialize the same class in an aggregate initialization and in either case **the second standard conversion sequence of `U1` is better than the second standard conversion sequence of `U2`**

Here we go, for both scenarios (with the converting constructor and the conversion function) the **second standard conversion** is of the same type (a temporary of type `to_type` to `to_type&&`), thus the operations are indistinguishable.

Comment: I think GCC might be implementing (and tripping over) [CWG 2327](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2327). I'm almost certain Clang might have (or had) a flag to enable something similar (although of course, the standard says what you quote).

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Both gcc and clang are wrong. Gcc is wrong because it uses copy ctor instead of conversion function. Only msvc correctly uses the conversion function. See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xn5v6Kzos)

Comment: @JasonLiam Could you please elaborate why you think the conversion function should take precedence here? Both converting constructor and conversion function return a temporary for which standard conversion to `A&&` is of identity category

Answer (score -2):

Clang is wrong in rejecting the program because an overload with `T&&` is better match than an overload with `const int&`. Note that gcc is also wrong because it uses the copy constructor instead of `operator to_type() const`. See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xn5v6Kzos). **Only msvc is right and both gcc and clang are wrong**. MSVC correctly uses the conversion function.

```
S1    S2
int   int&&         indistinguishable
int   const int&    indistinguishable
int&& const int&    S1 better
```

Consider the contrived example:

```
#include <iostream>
struct to_type;
struct from_type{
   operator to_type()const;
};
struct to_type{
   to_type() = default;
   to_type(const from_type&){std::cout <<"copy ctor";}
};
from_type::operator to_type()const{
    std::cout<<"to_type operator";
    return to_type();}

void f(to_type&&){}

int main(){
    from_type From; 
    f(From); //valid and this should use from_type::operator to_type() const

}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xn5v6Kzos)

The above program is rejected by clang(with the same error as you're getting) but accepted by gcc and msvc. Note that even though gcc accepts the above program it is still wrong because the conversion function should be used instead of the copy ctor. MSVC on the other hand correctly uses the conversion function.

Comment: Even assuming the move assignment would be selected, how would https://eel.is/c++draft/over.best.ics.general#12.sentence-4 not apply?